# Mysql выбрать записи date по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно выбрать записи date которых меньше текущей даты на 7 дней и не более чем 30  дней.

Пример:
*(Представим что сегодня 2018-11-28)*

```
id | Дата
1  | 2018-12-28
2  | 2018-12-22
3  | 2018-10-27
```

Должно отобразить только **вторую** запись. (2018-12-21) т.к. она попадает в этот промежуток
Моя неудачная попытка:

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM users 
WHERE user_last_activity <= CURDATE()-6 
  AND user_last_activity > CURDATE()-30
```

Comment: тип поля `user_last_activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Численное значение `YYYYMMDD`, возвращаемое функцией `CURDATE`, не будет давать верный результат при арифметических действиях, пересекающих границы месяца.

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM users WHERE 
user_last_activity <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND 
user_last_activity > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM users 
WHERE user_last_activity <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY 
  AND user_last_activity >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```